# Bootstrap tooltip should enable on change select box

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

The following example I want to show tooltip hover message when I select **option 1** from the select box. At the same time when I select option 2, option 3 and option 4 button should be disabled.

I have tried the below JavaScript code, But could not able to disable/enable the tooltip on hover.

Anyone help me to achieve this and drop your comments for further clarifications.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".btn-success").tooltip({ title: "test tooltip", container: "body", placement: "top", trigger: "hover" });
});
$("#opts").change(function () {
    var getopt = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
    console.log(getopt, "getopt");
    if (getopt == "option 1") {
        $(".btn-success").addClass("disabled");
    } else {
        $(".btn-success").removeClass("disabled");
    }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <select name="opts" id="opts" class="form-control">
                <option value="1">option 1</option>
                <option value="2">option 2</option>
                <option value="3">option 3</option>
                <option value="4">option 4</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="tooltip">Button Enable/Disable</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As my code below, you need to add `$('.btn-success').tooltip('enable' or 'disable')` like:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".btn-success").tooltip({ title: "test tooltip", container: "body", placement: "top", trigger: "hover" });
});
$("#opts").change(function () {
    var getopt = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
    console.log(getopt, "getopt");
    if (getopt !== "option 1") {
        $('.btn-success').tooltip('disable')
        $(".btn-success").addClass("disabled");
    } else {
        $('.btn-success').tooltip('enable')
        $(".btn-success").removeClass("disabled");
    }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <select name="opts" id="opts" class="form-control">
                <option value="1">option 1</option>
                <option value="2">option 2</option>
                <option value="3">option 3</option>
                <option value="4">option 4</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="tooltip">Button Enable/Disable</button>
</div>
```

When option 1 is selected all is active else all is disable.